# How to write junit for RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry in spring framework

Tags: rabbitmq, mockito, spring-rabbit, springjunit4classrunner

I have rest controller to start/stop rabbitmq QUEUE. That is working fine. But i need to write junit for this rest controller. I have done the junit as well but that does not looks good. I am not sure how better we can write junit for this rest controller.  Please help me to write better junit for this.

We are using spring framework and mockito in our project.

**My Rest Controller**

```java
package com.compnay.depart.rest;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class QueueController {
  
    private static final String LISTENER_ID = "lister";
    
    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
    

    @GetMapping(path = "/"+LISTENER_ID+"/start")
    public String start() {
        MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(LISTENER_ID);
        listenerContainer.start();
        return "started";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/"+LISTENER_ID+"/stop")
    public String stop() {
        MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(LISTENER_ID);
        listenerContainer.stop();
        return "stopped";
    }

    //This getter and setter method, i have created for JUNIT. 
    public RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry getRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry() {
        return rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
    }

    public void setRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry) {
        this.rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry = rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**This is my JUNIT**

```java
package com.compnay.depart.rest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
classes={  ObjectMapper.class})
public class QueueControllerTest 
 {

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Autowired
    public TraceabilityRestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @MockBean
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;
    
    public QueueController filingListnerController = new QueueController();
    
    @Before
    public void init() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    }

    @After
    public void shutdown() {
        server.reset();
    }


    @Test
    public void testStart() {
        when(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(anyString())).thenReturn(new MessageListenerContainer() {
            
            @Override
            public void stop() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void start() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isRunning() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            
            @Override
            public void setupMessageListener(MessageListener messageListener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public MessageConverter getMessageConverter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

       
        filingListnerController.setRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry);
        String response = filingListnerController.start();

        assertEquals("started", response);
    }
    

    @Test
    public void testStop() {
        when(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(anyString())).thenReturn(new MessageListenerContainer() {
            
            @Override
            public void stop() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void start() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isRunning() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            
            @Override
            public void setupMessageListener(MessageListener messageListener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public MessageConverter getMessageConverter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

       
        filingListnerController.setRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry);
        String response = filingListnerController.stop();

        assertEquals("stopped", response);
    }   
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? I would suggest `when(rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(MessageListenenerContainer.class));` to avoid all that boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell - I want to remove boiler plate code. This works.